AWS Bedrock Knowledge Base Sync Fail: (Invalid parameter combination....Issue occurred while processing file: <s3 file>. Call to null did not succeed
As the title suggest, I'm having issue syncing my knowledgebase. I have an arabic corpus that I want to sync and it has thousands of book. I took 2 books as a start to test syncing and this is where I encountered my problem. I put the corpus to s3.
My s3 folder looks like this where I created a file for each page for each book:
s3-bucket-folder
|__arabic_corpus
     |__book1
          |__volume-01---page-1.txt # the whole content is in arabic
          |__volume-01---page-1.txt.metadata.json
          |_ .....
     |__book2
          |__volume-01---page-1.txt # the whole content is in arabic
          |__volume-01---page-1.txt.metadata.json
          |_ ...

The total files are around 1500. However there are 100+ files that are failing that I don't get why it's failing. I've checked the CW logs and it doesn't seem to be that helpful. Here's an example error log from CW:
{"event_timestamp":1729478666096,"event":{"ingestion_job_id":"xx","document_location":{"type":"S3","s3_location":{"uri":"s3://xx/arabic_corpus/book1/volume-01---page-125.txt"}},"data_source_id":"xx","status_reasons":["Invalid parameter combination. Please check and try again. (Service: BedrockRuntime, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xx)"],"knowledge_base_arn":"arn:aws:bedrock:us-east-1:xx:knowledge-base/xx","status":"EMBEDDING_FAILED"},"event_version":"1.0","event_type":"StartIngestionJob.ResourceStatusChanged","level":"WARN"}

Here's its metadata
{
  "metadataAttributes": {
    "booktitle": "<title in arabic>",
    ....
    "page_id": "volume-01,-page-125"
  }
}

More context: I'm using no chunking strategy. The sync worked for 1400+ files, but 100+ files failed with this issue and I couldn't figure why it failed though.
The embedding models used for this Knowledge Base is:
cohere.embed-multilingual-v3

Is there a way I can re-produce the AWS Bedrock Knowledge Base Sync locally so I can try to reproduce it locally? I'm suspecting that there may be some invalid characters for those pages, but when I compare with success ones, I don't see anomalies.
I thought maybe .txt extension only supports ASCII as described here, but it's a bit weird since 1400 of arabic content pages worked. Nonetheless I tried updating the files to .md, .pdf, .html but it has same issue.
Each page is also less than 2048 characters.
I also removed .metadata.json files as part of debugging, but it would seem that the page contents itself is failing and not the metadata.
I asked the same question here https://repost.aws/questions/QUcaW7bsFQQICbQ5Ig0j7AtA/aws-bedrock-knowledge-base-sync-fail-invalid-parameter-combination-issue-occurred-while-processing-file-s3-file-call-to-null-did-not-succeed but not much progress is made here.
